# What is the best way to storing and then comparing personality questions?

Tags: php

I am working on a small dating site for my local area, and I am wondering the best way I can go about storing, retrieving, and then comparing the answers to another person. It wont just be one question, I will be creating over 1000 questions to be more specific on matches. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: The only answer we can give to such a vague and general question is **Use a database**. Stack Overflow is about *specific answerable* programming questions; Please attempt to solve your problem and comeback when you hit a specific road-block.

Comment: In addition to meagar's comment I suggest you to find a better idea than _working on a dating site_.

Comment: Don't listen to people who try to discourage you. You have to start somewhere, and I think that the logic you need for this will be something easy for you to figure out. The wildly successful dating website PlentyOfFish was started by a guy who was too cheap to buy an ASP.Net book, so he learned it by creating a test site. Read [this page](http://www.plentyoffish.com/about_team.aspx) for some inspiration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a **database approach**:

First, you need a table to hold the questions. It would have an ID column plus another column for the question text.

Then you need a table that holds user information. It would have a lot more columns, but the important one is the user ID.

Then you need a UserAnswer table to hold the users' answers. This table would have a column for user ID, a column for question ID, and a text column to hold the user's answer.

Then, when you want to retrieve a user's answers, you write a query to SELECT the answer text FROM the UserAnswer table WHERE the user ID in that table matches the ID of the user you want.

This is a very simplified version of one way to do this. I am hoping it gives you a general idea of where to start.